# javascript convert into parent-child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can anyone help converting the following list of parent-child objects:

I have below array of objects, Need to convert  it into parent child order. each 'Members' attribute in object may have 1 or n objects inside it. In 'Members' array the 1st object is parent of 2nd one and 2nd is parent of third object.

So in 1st Member 
 'Video' is parent of 'West' and 'West' is parent of 'India' and so on..

I have tried to loop through the elements one by one but could not reach the desired outcome.

Any help with the logic or code would be really helpful.

Input :

```
[
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Midwest"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Arab"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "NorthEast"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output :

````
[
  {
    "name": "Videos",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "West",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "India",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Japan",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "South",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Australia",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Machinery",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "South",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Australia",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "West",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "India",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Electronics",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Midwest",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Arab",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "NorthEast",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Japan",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

```
````

Comment: You have asked this before ?? ,I guess.Such questions need some efforts from your end ,that helps us to give you a better answer

Comment: @Shubh Yes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56643287/convert-array-of-object-into-parent-child-tree-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man this took too long. But it works with larger datasets. Note to OP, never use this data structure. Ever. It's horrible. I lost many braincells making this solution:

```js
var arr = [
  {Members: [{ Name: "Videos" }, { Name: "West" }, { Name: "India" }, {Name: 'Testing'}]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Machinery" }, { Name: "South" }, { Name: "Australia" }]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Electronics" }, { Name: "Midwest" }, { Name: "Arab" }]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Machinery" }, { Name: "West" }, { Name: "India" }]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Electronics" }, { Name: "NorthEast" }, { Name: "Japan" }]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Videos" }, { Name: "South" }, { Name: "Australia" }]},
  {Members: [{ Name: "Videos" }, { Name: "West" }, { Name: "Japan" }]}
];

const addRelation = (obj, m, i) => ({...obj, parent: i === 0 ? null : m.slice(0, i).map(el => el.Name).join('.'), level: i, children: []})

const arrayToTree = (arr) => {
    arr = arr.map(({ Members: m }) => m.map((obj, i) => addRelation(obj, m, i))).reduce((acc, arr) => {
        arr.map(obj => acc.push(obj))
        return acc
    }, []).sort((a, b) => b.level - a.level)    
    
    var temp = [...arr].filter((o, index, self) =>
        index === self.findIndex((t) => (
            t.Name === o.Name && t.parent === o.parent
        ))
    )

    arr.forEach(() => {
        if (temp[0].level === 0) return
        var parentIndex = temp.findIndex(o => {
            var str = temp[0].parent
            var rest = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
            var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, str.length);
            var parents = [rest, last]
            return parents[0] !== ''
              ? o.Name === parents[1] && o.parent === parents[0]
              : o.Name === temp[0].parent
        })
        const { Name, children } = temp[0]
        temp[parentIndex].children.push({Name, children})
        temp.shift()
    })
        
    return temp.map(({ Name, children }) => ({ Name, children }))
}

arr = arrayToTree(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Hello, we meet again. :D. your answer is way better than mine so dont take this in a wrong way but it does not reproduce the desired output.

Comment: @Andam I fixed that just now :)

Comment: It does work but its not the same structure as his expected outcome

Comment: @Andam Can you please point where i went wrong so i can fix it

Comment: You did not went wrong but his outcome is like this Videos > West > India, Japan but your answer is Videos > West > India, Videos  > West > Japan

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed that, I'll fix that now, thanks.

Comment: I failed doing it in .map myself so Im interested in seeing your result

Comment: What @Adnam said is correct. The output is not aligned to the expected output. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Any ways thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kobe - Its adding one extra/ duplicate  child "West" to "video". I can really understand the amount of efforts it consumed. Thanks.

Comment: @Kracki fixed :)

Comment: Thankyou :) I shouldn't have taken so long, but the lack of relationships really threw me halfway through

Comment: @Kracki I agree with Kobe it would have been way easier if you had a correct structure for you data.

Comment: @Andam - Yes I agree with you. But I dont have any other option apart from handling such data. Thanks for help  :-)

Comment: I just like the effort that has been put into this, to help another. +1

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way to go about this and this only works for 3 levels.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Midwest"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Arab"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "NorthEast"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [
      {
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function organize(dataBefore){
  var dataAfter = [];
  
 dataAfter.push({
    name: dataBefore[0].Members[0].Name,
    children: []
  });
    
  for(var i = 1; i < dataBefore.length; i++){
    if(!doesExist(dataAfter, dataBefore[i].Members[0].Name)){
      dataAfter.push({
        name: dataBefore[i].Members[0].Name,
        children: []
      });
    }
  }

  dataAfter[0].children.push({
    name: dataBefore[0].Members[1].Name,
    children: []
  });

  for(var i = 1; i < dataBefore.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < dataAfter.length; j++){
          if(dataAfter[j].name == dataBefore[i].Members[0].Name){
            if(!doesExist(dataAfter[j].children, dataBefore[i].Members[1].Name)){
                dataAfter[j].children.push({
                    name: dataBefore[i].Members[1].Name,
                    children: []
                });
            }
          }
      }
  }

  dataAfter[0].children[0].children.push({
    name: dataBefore[0].Members[2].Name,
    children: []
  });

  for(var i = 1; i < dataBefore.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < dataAfter.length; j++){
        if(dataAfter[j].name == dataBefore[i].Members[0].Name){
            for(var k = 0; k < dataAfter[j].children.length; k++){
                if(dataAfter[j].children[k].name == dataBefore[i].Members[1].Name){
                    if(!doesExist(dataAfter[j].children[k].children, dataBefore[i].Members[2].Name)){
                        dataAfter[j].children[k].children.push({
                            name: dataBefore[i].Members[2].Name,
                            children: []
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
  }

  return dataAfter;
}

function doesExist(checkThisData, searchValue){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkThisData.length; i++){
        if(searchValue == checkThisData[i].name){
            return true;
        }
    }
  
    return false;
}

console.log(organize(data));
```

Comment: This is very over complicated :p

Comment: @Adnam - Thanks for the code , It works very well for the level 3 . By any chance can you help in in any way for not restricting it to only level 3. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: yes I believe I can. I will try and get back to you

Comment: I can't come up with a solution lol. The data structure is horrendous :p +1, Nicely done. I'll continue trying though ;)

Comment: @Andam finally made one :)

Comment: @Kobe fantastic. Yes, I looked at the results. I think its still different or it might be my eyes messing with me.

Comment: @Andam I made sure it was right this time around :) Always nice to have a challenge

Comment: @Kobe Yes, I agree. The challenge is the fun part here. About the result I think you have an extra node in the beginning. you have two videos > west nodes in the answer. as far as I figured out.

Comment: @Kobe you came pretty far Im sure you can figure this out and fix it. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to use map + reduce combination:

```js
const data = [{
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Midwest"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Arab"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Machinery"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "India"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Electronics"
      },
      {
        "Name": "NorthEast"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Australia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Members": [{
        "Name": "Videos"
      },
      {
        "Name": "West"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Japan"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const ar = data.map((el, i) => {
  let a = el['Members'].reduce((acc, member, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      acc[index] = {
        name: member.Name,
        children: []
      };
    } else {
      debugger;
      if (acc[0].children.length === 0) {
        acc[0].children.push({
          name: member.Name,
          children: []
        });
      } else {
        acc[0].children[0].children.push({
          name: member.Name,
          children: []
        });
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return a;
});

console.log(ar);
```

Comment: your answer like kobe answer does not reproduce the same result as his result.  his outcome is like this Videos > West > India, Japan but your answer is Videos > West > India, Videos > West > Japan